# Unit Testing map.catch angular4 services

Tags: angular, angular2-services

Can any one please suggest how to test the below catch function in spec.ts file?

```
 getTemplate(){
        this._http.get('http//localhost:8080/new').map((response : Response) => response.json())).catch(this.serverError);
      }
      private serverError(err: any) {
        console.log('sever error:', err); // debug
        if(err instanceof Response) {
         //return Observable.throw(err.json().error || 'backend server error');
          // if you're using lite-server, use the following line
          // instead of the line above:
        return Observable.throw(err.text() || 'backend server error');
        }
        return Observable.throw(err || 'backend server error');
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to test that you need to receive the HttpErrorResponse from the server. To test this you can write a small interceptor, and throw an error while monitoring the response, then your catch will be triggered.

Check this post out, it has reference to both how to write an interceptor and how to generate the httperror response when requied,

https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/angular-4-3-httpclient-accessing-rest-web-services-with-angular-2305b8fd654b

In the code below you also need to make sure that all the setup and imports are done properly, below code snippet will trigger the httperror response, to be precise it would be Http 404.

**Update 1**

here is how a sample test case file would look like, assume your service name is *YourService*

```
import {Injectable, ReflectiveInjector} from '@angular/core';
import {async, fakeAsync, tick} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {BaseRequestOptions, ConnectionBackend, Http, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import {Response, ResponseOptions} from '@angular/http';
import {MockBackend, MockConnection} from '@angular/http/testing';

import { YourService } from './serviceIndependent.service';


describe('MockBackend NameService Example', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    this.injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
      {provide: ConnectionBackend, useClass: MockBackend},
      {provide: RequestOptions, useClass: BaseRequestOptions},
      Http,
      YourService,
    ]);
    this.yourService = this.injector.get(YourService);
    this.backend = this.injector.get(ConnectionBackend) as MockBackend;
    this.backend.connections.subscribe((connection: any) => this.lastConnection = connection);
  });


  it('getNames() while server is not Reachable', fakeAsync(() => {
       let result: String[];
       let catchedError: any;
       this.yourService.getNames()
           .then((names: String[]) => result = names)
           .catch((error: any) => catchedError = error);
       this.lastConnection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({
         status: 404,
         statusText: 'URL not Found',
       })));
       tick();
       expect(result).toBeUndefined();
       expect(catchedError).toBeDefined();
     }));
});
```

Comment: Can i send error response as mock response and inject the serveError method and spyOn it?

Comment: if you are using httpcodule you can spy on and send the response using Response and Response options, if you are using httpClient there is a difference and easy way of sending the mocked response, let me know which one you use?

Comment: i am using {Headers, RequestOptions, Http, Response} from '@angular/http';

Comment: Ok get that let me correct my answer accordingly give me a while. Meanwhile I would suggest you migrate your code in HttpClient, Http is the older implementation and it may not be supported in the later release of Angular. Nevertheless I will write a small piece of code in Http error handling such that you can then see how to get an .catch work.

Comment: sure sir thanks in advance!! there are a lot of efforts in changing to httpclient, i ll surely do that in future.

Comment: but how about the code which I have written in the answer, did that work?